# Bison doesn't output color

Tags: linux, terminal, bison

`bison -Wcex --yacc --output=alpha_syntaxer.cpp --color yyalpha.yacc --defines`

`bison (GNU Bison) 3.8.2`

How to get color output from bison? ..
I tried all the color options , but nothing.
My terminal ( `echo $TERM xterm-kitty` ) supports colors.